# Rails 3 Associations for Traffic Data without Foreign Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have to define an association that doesn't seem to fit in well to the "has_one / belongs_to" bucket very well.

The situation is this, I have a table whereby each row corresponds to monthly statistics for a given month and year.  I'd love to be able to define certain associations on my model such as `record.prior_month` or `record.prior_year` which would correspond to the prior month / year of the current record.

I can't think of any clever way to do this as it doesn't make any sense to maintain foreign keys that would have to be updated every month for tons of records.

I can always handle the logic in the controller, but I'd prefer to keep it with the model if I could.

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 0):

So rather than store the Month/Year, also store the Month+Year*12. So March 2011 is 24135

That way, you know the next month is 21436, and you can easily paginate over your records.

```
TrafficGroup.order("month_calculated").paginate(:page=>params[:page])
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse - pagination is great but I don't think it'll help me with the eventual task.  The goal isn't so much to display these records and let users paginate through them as much as perform calculations like a certain metric's change over prior month.

Comment: ahh, then your problem is more of how to appropriately group mass amounts of data. Not how to display already grouped data.

Comment: Yeah - although the idea of adding the julian date type column isn't a bad one. It'll certainly help with some other things I'm doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
class MyModel < AR::Base
  def prior_month
    created_at.month
  end

  def prior_year
    created_at.year
  end
end

example = MyModel.last
example.prior_year
#=> 2010
example.prior_month
#=> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a few ways. Assuming the month is stored in the model.

My favorite is scopes, since it plays nicely with other associations.

For instance you can do:

```
class TrafficRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :only_month, lambda {|month| where :month => month} # this should also contain join conditions

  def prior_month
    self.class.only_month(self.month - 1) #decrement your month
  end
end
```